# How to make a string available in all the forms in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, connection-string

I'm using Compact Framework 2.0 for an application in Windows CE 5.0 device with multiple forms.

I have to use a connection string in almost all the forms in order to access to the database:

```
string conString = "Data Source=\\Program Files\\myproject\\database.sdf";
```

I would like to know if it's possible to make this connection string somehow "global" in order to be written only once and accessible from all the forms.

Comment: You should never hardcode connection strings. Add it to the application's configuration file instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per @Steven's comment, you should really add this in the config file, however see below for an example of what you asked for.

Create a class for it and make it a public const field.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public const string conString = "Data Source=\\Program Files\\myproject\\database.sdf"; 
}
```

Then in your forms (or anywhere else) you could access it as `Globals.conString`.

Comment: +1.  I'd probably mark the class as being static as well if it is going to contain nothing but static values.

Comment: I have nothing against doing it using the application's configuration file if that's the best way. But I think compact-framework does not support app.config files (correct me if I'm wrong). So I think I must use a class like the one you've written. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For more flexibility you can use **readonly** keyword. Readonly members are initilized at runtime and can hold complex objects.

```
public class DataBaseConfiguration
{
     public readonly String conStr;

     public DataBaseConfiguration(String conString)
     {
          this.conString = conString;
     }
}
```